# AJAX async doesn't work

Tags: javascript, ajax

I try send 16 asynchronous request's to my back-end .

```
$.each(response, function( k, v ) {
    uploadAdditionalRows(v)
});

function uploadAdditionalRows(value) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/asins/table_data/" + encodeURIComponent(value),
                    cache:false,
                    type: "GET",
                    success: function(response) {
                        console.log(response);
                    }
                });

                return;
            }
```

But they return execute 1 after another.

[image]

How get response like this ? :

[image]

Comment: as @Igor said. HTTP requests take time to initiate and you cannot start so many at the same time... But your calls do not wait the end of the other, they are therefor async. Try a Sync ajax, you'll see what it does. It actually completely freeze the browser.

Comment: Seeing that your responses are only a couple bytes, you should definitely increase the amount of data you send per request...

Comment: Now it's just empty response.

Comment: Now you changed the question... You want them to go 5 by 5? Then send 5 requests, wait for them all, and resend 5...

Comment: Yes, I want get 5 response then send another 5

Answer (score 5):

Browsers enforce a limit on the number of simultaneous HTTP connections they will open (and a smaller limit on the number of connections to any given domain).

If you exceed that limit, the requests enter a queue.

You can see this in that the first four start at the same time, then the rest are delayed.

Comment: I see, but what a solution ?

Comment: The only work around that is to limit HTTP calls you need to make... One could use server-side scripts to aggregate requests or something.

Comment: How get response like in second picture ?